# How to execute :action before rendering its view using "render" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand that `render :action` only renders an action's view. But I was wondering.. Is there no easy way to execute the code in that action before its view is rendered?

Comment: What is the problem with redirect_to :action => "bar" as said by shime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to reuse logic in two different controllers why not just pull that logic out of its current controller into something more reusable like a helper method or class?

Comment: Now that I realize that I have no other option, I'll ultimately have to do this. I was just trying to find something as simple as 'render' which executes an action's code in and addition to rendering it's view.

Comment: I see how that could be convenient but it has always seemed weird to me to call a controllers action from another controller (yes, I have wanted to do this in the past as well). If there is logic that is reusable in multiple parts of the application then it should not belong to an action. In my opinion, actions are not meant to be reusable. They are very specific to the responsibility of their parent controller.

Comment: Another option (one that I am currently thinking about) to share controller/action and view is the Cell gem https://github.com/apotonick/cells.

Comment: The `cells` gem is great. It indeed answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

```
class TestolaController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    redirect_to :action => "bar"
  end

  def bar
    puts "in bar"
  end
end
```

Comment: A redirect won't work for me because I'm trying to execute another method from another controller and fetch it's output for use in my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def foo
    bar
  end

  def bar
    puts "in bar"
  end
```

Comment: This shall execute another method from the same controller. I'm trying to execute one from a different controller.

Comment: Plus... in your method... will 'bar' method only be executed inside 'foo' or shall it return the 'bar' view as well? because I want to do both.

Comment: ok...no in this method it will only execute bar method and return foo view

Comment: you can use `before_filter :bar, only: ['foo']` but your bar method should be in the same controller or application controller